# One seed phrase created two wallets with two script types

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, lightning-network, backup

I have a wallet on blockchain.com and it is saved with the backup phrase. Due to issues I was not able to buy anything there, so I created an account at coinbase. This lead to the usage of coinbase wallet. I imported the wallet with the phrase. Everything went well unti I added coins from coinbase. This new amount appeared only in the coinbase wallet.
So now I figured out using Electrum that I have created two wallets. One with with script type p2pkh and one with p2wpkh. Both summed togehter cointains my whole number of coins.
How can I proceed to put all in one wallet together?
Since support on blockchain.com is not able to help I want to have all at one place again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I proceed to put all in one wallet together?

1. Decide which wallet you want the coins to end up in
2. Open that wallet, copy a receiving address from it
3. Open the other wallet, send all funds from it to the address you copied above (be sure to double check that the address you paste matches!)
4. Wait for transaction confirmation. Once confirmed, all your funds will be in available in that one wallet

It is not technically impossible to have a wallet handle addresses that are different script types, but I'm not sure I know of any wallets that include this functionality.

Comment: I think we can have both types of addresses in same Electrum Wallet with some workaround. Remember doing it or saw in some video. Will have to try